# What's the most efficient way to evaluate an IF condition?

Tags: c++, if-statement, interpreter, evaluation, evaluate

I'm making a language interpreter and I've gotten to the point where I need to evaluate if statements. At first I thought it was simple, I was able to make my interpreter evaluate simple if conditions like this, `10 == 10` but then when I tried to make it evaluate a more complicated condition, `10 == 10 and 9 > 2` for example, it messed up.

I made some code C++ code that can evaluate each part of a condition individually, for example.

```
"Hello World" == "Hello World" or "Test" == "Test"
```

It currently works like this, it gives the actual result above and the expected result below. This result of this would be:

```
TRUE or TRUE           <- Actual
-----------------------
TRUE or TRUE           <- Expected
-----------------------
```

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>    
#include "cond.h"

using namespace std;

vector <string> cond_holder;
vector <string> res;
vector <string> expects;

bool eval_cond(string cond) {
    int i;
    int i2;
    bool state = 0;
    bool final_return = false;
    string c = "";

    for (i = 0; i < cond.length();i++) {
        c += cond[i];

        if (cond[i] == '"') {
            if (state == 0)
                state = 1;
            else
                state = 0;
        } else if (cond[i] == ' ' && state == 0) {
            c = c.substr(0,c.length()-1);
            cond_holder.push_back(c);
            c = "";

        }
        if (i == cond.length()-1) {
            cout << c << endl;      
        }

    }
    for (i = 0; i < cond_holder.size();i++) {
        if (cond_holder[i+1] == "eqeq") {
            expects.push_back("TRUE");
            if (cond_holder[i] == cond_holder[i+2]) {
                res.push_back("TRUE");
            } else {
                res.push_back("FALSE");
            }
            i+=3;
        }
        if (cond_holder[i] == "and") {
            res.push_back("and");
            expects.push_back("and");
        } else if (cond_holder[i] == "or") {
            res.push_back("or");
            expects.push_back("or");
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < res.size();i++) {
        cout << res[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl << "-----------------------" << endl;

    for (i = 0; i < expects.size();i++) {
        cout << expects[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl << "-----------------------" << endl;

    return final_return;
}

int main() {
    cout << eval_cond("string:\"Hello World\" eqeq string:\"Hello World\" or string:\"H\" eqeq string:\"H\" ") << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Honestly though, I just made the code up as I went along, so I'd be grateful if someone could tell me a better way to do it. I'm not even sure what to do with this code next.

Comment: So you're not having trouble with if statements, just with evaluating more complicated expressions.

Comment: @Chris yea. I'd like to use whatever help I get with IF statements to help me with other things, like while loops, for loops etc ...

Comment: If you want efficiency, pass cond by const reference and don't use substr, which makes copies, but assign/insert and find instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
Variable is an expression
Number is an expression
String is an expression
Expression == Expression is an expression
Expression AND Expression is an expression
Expression ; is a statement
IF Expression { statement } is a statement
```

Build your language out of bits like that, and let it all just collapse together.  The old unix manual for Flex and Yacc was a good introduction to the topic.